# I need the ODBC SQL driver 17.2.01 MSI

Tags: sql, odbc, version, driver

I need to upgrade Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 17 (AKA ssms) or perhaps just the ODBC SQL driver because when I try to open a DB from copied datafiles (mdf and ldf) that came from another machine it cannot be opened because it is version 869. And my machine apparently supports version 852 and earlier.

If I want to sideload the latest ssms 18.4, I can't upgrade because it needs to remove that version. There's a pop-up that it needs 'Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server' (that needs a msodbcsql.msi file).

So I need the msi of that specific version, could anyone provide this for me because I can't find it anywhere online. :-(

I even ran the FixMissingMSI tool that scans your system for missing msi's:
https://github.com/suyouquan/SQLSetupTools

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem today. Performed uninstall of ODBC 17 driver using following tool from Microsoft,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed

After doing this SSMS setup was successful.

Comment: Nice, that actually seems to work! I can install the latest version of SSMS but it seems like ODBC version 17 still is installed (but perhaps I need to reboot).